# owncloud cannot access directory

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, owncloud

I am running Raspbian version 7 on my raspberry pi.  I am running owncloud on this.  I have mounted an external drive under /media/Owncloud.  This is where I have owncloud store all the files.  I cannot access this directory.  When I try `cd /media/Owncloud` it gives me the following error:
`-bash: cd: /media/Owncloud/: Permission denied`

How can I access this directory?

Answer (score 5):

OwnCloud and external hard drives are tricky and you have a permission issue. For some reason, trying to make a link to an external hard drive has issues, so you need to try mounting your external hard drive.

External hard drive - Apply the proper group and read permissions:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/user/your_hard_drive/owncloud_data/
chmod -R 777 /media/user/your_hard_drive/owncloud_data/
```

Local hard drive - Apply the proper group and read permissions:

```
mkdir /var/www/owncloud/data
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/owncloud/data
chmod -R 777 /var/www/owncloud/data
```

Make the mount of local hard drive to external hard drive

```
mount --bind /media/user/your_hard_drive/owncloud_data/ /var/www/owncloud/data/
```

Source:

- https://manandkeyboard.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/owncloud-and-an-external-hard-drive/

Comment: My friend, Thank you. This is the only answer that worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access /media/Owncloud, you need to set the proper permissions.  Run the command `sudo chmod 755 /media/Owncloud`(for more security relative to permission 777).

You also may need to allow to webserver to access the directory.  In order to do that, run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/Owncloud`

Sources:
My own experience and frusteration in running into the exact same problem
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Owncloud-dropbox-clone/?ALLSTEPS A great albeit somewhat outdated guide to set up owncloud on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @q33q3 Your answer is correct, however setting the permissions to 777 might create a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `cd` into the directory, change to root with `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with wrong permissions.

If the webserver runs as user www-data, the mounted folder must be somehow accessible to that user

- either that user must be owner of mounted folder and its contents, and have the "user" permissions, or
- the the folder must be accessible to the group the webserver user is in (usually www-data).

To see the current permissions use the `ls -l` command.

To change the owner use `chown` command,

to change the permissions for the user-owner, and group-owner, use the `chmod` command,

or just use Midnight commander (`mc`) or some GUI to do that.

If you are mounting the external volume through `/etc/fstab` check the options in there. I would not recommend using the volume with some dynamic mounting (like the file managers do (gvfs-fuse)) if is a key folder for a webserver with ownCloud and you need to have it auto-mounted on boot, as some specific user that the webserver is run as.

I have an experience with having the ownCloud data folder on `/srv/data` (also ownCloud 7.0 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 VPS), the permissions are 770 and the owner is www-data:www-data, and in the ownCloud config file, I use the line

`'datadirectory' => '/srv/data',`

I would not recommend using 777 permissions, as it is not a good security practice in general.